# How to Create button dynamically mvc using list and sql database column

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller

I have code That work in create button dynamically in mvc. The problem is i have column call estates when we enter new estates ,it should create new button dyamically in the view page...

Here I done some of function it will create button using list.now i want to using sql column. When we enter new data in the sql column(Esates) it should create new button dyamically with the name what we entered in the sql column.

```
  List<Estates> estates = new List<Estates>
  {
    new Estates { Estate_ID = 1 , EstateName = "Annfiled"},
    new Estates { Estate_ID = 2 , EstateName = "Battalgalla"},
    new Estates { Estate_ID = 3 , EstateName = "Fordyce"},
   };
```

This view Code

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <button type="submit" id="Estate_id_Button" class="Estates_button">@item.EstateName
    </button>
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What you wrote on your view with razor creates buttons based on Model (assuming you've bound `@model List<Estates>` to your view you only need to get data from database as List of Estates and pass it to view

Comment: Clearly tell me what you want to do now?

Comment: What ORM (Object-relational mapping) are you using?

Comment: I just want to create dynamic button using list I have a code for list now I need to code for loop for from SQL column need to create button  when we enter the data in the SQL column we need to create button  in the mvc view

Comment: What you need is a method to get the list of Estates from database? so you can loop through the code you wrote on view?

Comment: How to write using  above  code I have no idea can you please help

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach loop to loop through your data and create buttons.

Comment: How to code in for each can you help using sql column it is urgent